# PHP help me About preg_replace

Tags: php

I have the following issue: (sorry little English )

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '�' in /home/u107658206/public_html/moter_select.php on line 187
```

My code is as follows

```
<?php

        function CheckRude($temp) { 
            $wordchange = ("<font color=red>**</font>"); 
            $sql = "select * from rude";
            $dbquery = mysql_query($sql);
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($dbquery);
            $i = 0;
            while ($i < $num_rows) {
                $result = mysql_fetch_array($dbquery);
                $temp = preg_replace($result['rude_name'], $wordchange, $temp);
                $i++;
            }
            return ( $temp );
        }

$comment_new = CheckRude($r_comment['text_post']);
        ?>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: There's something wrong in `$result['rude_name']`, which you haven't shown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier ...](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+Warning:%20preg_replace():%20Unknown%20modifier)

Comment: 1st argument should be an regexp so use "/".$resutl['rude-name']."/"

Answer (score 0):

```
mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
```

You don't seem to have the knowledge of the fundamental purpose of `preg_replace`

You need a pattern to look for. I see that you are trying to replace something with the `$wordChange` value.

```
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $result['rude_name']);
```

For instance, lets say I want to replace A in a string with B: I would call it like this:

```
$my_string = "Hello, A, World, A";

$var = preg_replace('/A/', 'B', $my_string);
```

Comment: I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `$result['rude_name']` contains just simple string.

For `preg_replace()` to work, you have to have an opening and closing `#` or `/`.

So you'd have something like:

```
$temp = preg_replace("/".$result['rude_name']."/", $wordchange, $temp);
```